# How come my Unity 3d camera is grey (New to Unity)

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, camera

[Picture of camera that is following the Player](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqCOy.png)
Now my problem is that it's only grey, and I don't know why. I've tried adjusting the camera angle but I may be doing that wrong. Please help!

I rotated the camera in different ways but I may have done it wrong.

Comment: Because its not looking at what you are

Comment: @BugFinder please explain how to make it look at it

Comment: Where is the camera?  Click on the camera in the `hierarchy` and press `f` to focus on it.

Comment: If you look at the menu one is align to object so you can click on your camera click that to confirm where its or theres align object to view which makes the selected object point from where you are at the same angle you are

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the camera look at what you're looking at in the scene view, you can simply just use ctrl + shift + F.

More unity hotkeys: https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.1/Documentation/Manual/UnityHotkeys.html

If the issue is stil there, try resseting your camera component.